# Disable click-to-edit on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediawiki installation. When I double-click on text, mediawiki goes into edit mode. I don't like this, because I want to use double-click for selecting text. (I actually use triple-click for selecting a paragraph because I have a Mac and it just works.)

How do I disable double-click to edit?

I'm happy to disable it individual users, or disable it system-wide. I'm the only user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from your question if you want to disable this for you as a user, or change the default setting.

In the latter case, as an administrator, add this line to your LocalSettings.php:
$wgDefaultUserOptions['editondblclick'] = 0;
Though the default setting in a fresh MediaWiki install is '0', or 'false' (at least in the latest stable version, MediaWiki 1.34)

If you want to disable it for you as a logged-in user:
Go to the page Special:Preferences, click on 'Editing' and deselect 'Edit pages on double click'. Be sure to save.

If the default setting was '1' and you want to disable it for all existing users, you can use the script: [UserOptions.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:UserOptions.php)

Documentation on this setting can be found at: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDefaultUserOptions#Default_values

Comment: Thanks so much. I clarified my question.